# How can I run a container from nvidia/cuda:12.0.1-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu22.04 using `--gpus` option?

Tags: docker, gpu, wsl-2, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to run a docker container created from the image `nvidia/cuda:12.0.1-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu22.04`, using Ubuntu 22.04 under WSL 2 version 1.1.3.0 in Windows 11 and Docker Desktop  4.17.1. Running `lsb_release -a` confirms the version of Ubuntu:

```
user@desktop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

In Docker Desktop, the option "Use the WSL 2 based engine" is checked in Settings -> General, as is "Enable integration with my default WSL distro" in Settings -> Resources -> WSL integration. On the same page, "Enable integration with additional distros:" is switched on for Ubuntu-22.04.

Running `nvidia-smi` from an Ubuntu terminal produces

```
user@desktop:~$ nvidia-smi
Tue Mar 21 22:43:15 2023
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.89.02    Driver Version: 528.49       CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A200...  On   | 00000000:F3:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   61C    P8     4W /  17W |     40MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A        32      G   /Xwayland                       N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A        34      G   /Xwayland                       N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13020      G   /Xwayland                       N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For what's worth, running `nvidia-smi.exe` from a PowerShell terminal produces a similar but not identical result; the version of NVIDIA-SMI shows as 528.49 in Windows instead of 525.89.02 as seen above in Ubuntu.

Running the container without `--gpus` produces the expected result right away, i.e., a working container without GPU functionality:

```
user@desktop:~$ docker run -it nvidia/cuda:12.0.1-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu22.04

==========
== CUDA ==
==========

CUDA Version 12.0.1

Container image Copyright (c) 2016-2022, NVIDIA CORPORATION & AFFILIATES. All rights reserved.

This container image and its contents are governed by the NVIDIA Deep Learning Container License.
By pulling and using the container, you accept the terms and conditions of this license:
https://developer.nvidia.com/ngc/nvidia-deep-learning-container-license

A copy of this license is made available in this container at /NGC-DL-CONTAINER-LICENSE for your convenience.

WARNING: The NVIDIA Driver was not detected.  GPU functionality will not be available.
   Use the NVIDIA Container Toolkit to start this container with GPU support; see
   https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/ .

root@80a1fd519f3a:/#
```

Multiple attempts to run the container with `--gpus 0`, `--gpus 1`, or `--gpus all` produced no output within one hour, after which I closed the terminal window - CTRL+C did not stop execution.

The outcomes above were observed also with Ubuntu 20.04 and variants of the CUDA image, such as `nvidia/cuda:11.6.0-deve-ubuntu20.04` and `nvidia/cuda:12.1.0-ubuntu22.04`. I also tried breaking down the running of the container into separate create and start steps; the issues described still occur at the start step.

I have benefited from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185405/using-gpu-from-a-docker-container), in particular the last answer, from August 2, 2020. Related questions such as [pytorch cannot detect gpu in nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04 base image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75455717/pytorch-cannot-detect-gpu-in-nvidia-cuda11-3-1-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20-04-base)  refer to issues *after* the container starts, but I do not get to that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems version 4.17.1 of docker-desktop is broken. CUDA containers worked fine in <=4.17.0 for me but, after upgrading to 4.17.1, the container start-up process just hangs.

Comment: from a new contributor to another, welcome. I rolled my Docker Desktop installation in Windows back to 4.17.0 and everything works perfectly. Moreover, it worked even with my images created using version 4.17.1, so all I had to do was to recreate the containers, which was trivial. Many thanks!